# PayPal node sdk causing CORs error "Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request" even after enabling headers

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, paypal, ejs

I'm trying to redirect using a POST request handled by nodejs backend with the following headers:

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Accept': 'application/json'
```

We want to redirect the customer to the Paypal payment link using res.redirect on the server side. However we experience the cors error:

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
```

Originally, we had a CORs issue that stated that

```
Access to fetch at *** from origin *** has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
```

However, now our error relates to the preflight request. We have tried changing the headers (which fixed the previous issue) however it is essential that we keep the application/json header (on the client side) as this is our method of sending basket (item ID and quantity) to the backend to be verified before redirecting to the payment page. We think that this could be an issue with the fact that this is a POST request not allowing information from the body to be sent back and then going ahead with a redirect. We have gone on basically every similar thread trying to resolve this problem without any luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/issues/348